# Multiple products of varying size and color on 1 order submit

Tags: magento

I am looking to make a product that offers several sizes and colors, and allow the customer to select different sizes and colors (and quantities of each) on one page and submit to add several variations at once to the cart

example:  Customer wants to order

```
10 Small Black shirts
10 Medium Black shirts
20 Large Black shirts
5 Small White shirts
5 Medium White shirts
10 Large Black shirts
```

they input the numbers in a grid view on the "Product View" page and click submit once, adding 60 products to their cart at once

I have looked for add-on and mods that are already created for either purchase or free and could not find any.

Comment: I think you could customize the view logic of configurable product

Answer (score 0):

I coded a theme like this. The way I did it was to use simple products. Build a page, as you suggest, that has an HTML form for the user to indicate which product_id and what quantities and then have that form submit a JSON POST of {product_id:qty} pairs to a custom controller that can then recover product_id=>qty pairs from the POST and then loop over $cart->addProduct($product,$request); for each object in the POST.

So in your custom controller, you can get an array of `$product_id=>$qty` from something like

```
$lolo_skusToAdd = $this->getRequest()->getParam('skuJson',false);
$testArray = json_decode($lolo_skusToAdd, true);

//...

  foreach($testArray as $sku=>$qty){
    //Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->addProduct() wants quantity as a Varien Object
    $request = new Varien_Object(array('qty' => $qty));

    //...    

    $eventArgs = array(
                 'product' => $product,
                 'qty' => $qty,
                 'additional_ids' => array(),
                 'request' => $this->getRequest(),
             'response' => $this->getResponse(),
                 ); 

    Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_before_add', $eventArgs);

    try{

        $cart->addProduct($product,$request);
        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_after_add', $eventArgs);

        //...
```

I've left a lot of code out. My controller is a bit messy and actually specialised for a custom situation: it uses ajax to receive the POST and return either success messages or failure messages.

I hope this has given you some pointers in the right direction. If you go this way you should read the normal add to cart controllers to see how 'default Magento' adds products to the cart and mimic that in your custom controller so you can include all the Mage::dispatchEvents() and the $cart->save() and the session message updates etc etc